# Nutch 1.2 crawl throws system cannot find the path specified

Tags: nutch

I'm currently looking at Nutch 1.2. I've got a (simplified) batch file:

```
CD c:\nutch-1.2\win32\bin
CALL nutch crawl c:\nutch-1.2\urls -dir c:\nutch-1.2\crawl -depth 5 -topN 50
PAUSE
```

Attempting to run this as an administrator on command prompt and I get a "The system cannot find the file specified."

I've checked the directory and file path and can confirm that the `urls` directory exists as well as `crawl`. The `urls` have a single text file `urls.txt` with a single entry: http://dev.example.com

I've doubled check the documentation for the [crawl](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20crawl) command too.

Could I have missed anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was a red herring. The parameters weren't the issue.

The issue is that when running `crawl`, the referenced `JAVA_HOME` is empty which is why the error is thrown. I've referenced the latest updated version and the command is now running as expected.